# Im new in creating android apps, but for now the splash screen doesnt work, and as i see no error, the app just wont start in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im using the Android Studio, the latest version. Im successfully create a simple cardview ui, and intended to add splash screen, however the apps wont work. i put the code here too. Please help me.

This is the androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DASHBOARD">
    <activity android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    </activity>
</application>
```

this is splash java

```
    package com.example.dashboard;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView logo,splashImg;
    TextView appName;
    LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
        appName = findViewById(R.id.appname);
        splashImg = findViewById(R.id.img);
        lottieAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.lottie);

        splashImg.animate().translationY(-1600).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
        logo.animate().translationY(1400).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
        appName.animate().translationY(1400).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
        lottieAnimationView.animate().translationY(1400).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(4000);
    }
}
```

this is the main activity java

```
    package com.example.dashboard;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

really appreciate answers guys thanks

edit/ here the stacktrace

```
2021-01-27 16:53:53.118 10697-10697/? I/ample.dashboar: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2021-01-27 16:53:53.170 10697-10697/? W/ample.dashboar: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-01-27 16:53:53.497 10697-10697/com.example.dashboard W/ample.dashboar: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
2021-01-27 16:53:53.497 10697-10697/com.example.dashboard W/ample.dashboar: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-01-27 16:53:53.497 10697-10697/com.example.dashboard W/ample.dashboar: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-01-27 16:53:53.498 10697-10697/com.example.dashboard W/ample.dashboar: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-01-27 16:53:53.498 10697-10697/com.example.dashboard W/ample.dashboar: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
2021-01-27 16:53:53.526 10697-10697/com.example.dashboard W/ample.dashboar: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2021-01-27 16:53:53.526 10697-10697/com.example.dashboard W/ample.dashboar: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2021-01-27 16:53:53.559 10697-10697/com.example.dashboard W/ample.dashboar: Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic; (light greylist, linking)
2021-01-27 16:53:53.596 10697-10697/com.example.dashboard D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2021-01-27 16:53:53.646 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe2ea6f90, tid 10724
2021-01-27 16:53:53.664 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2021-01-27 16:53:53.667 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2021-01-27 16:53:53.669 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2021-01-27 16:53:53.669 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2021-01-27 16:53:53.670 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2021-01-27 16:53:53.670 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2021-01-27 16:53:53.670 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2021-01-27 16:53:53.692 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
2021-01-27 16:53:53.692 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe49f7320: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2021-01-27 16:53:53.710 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe49f7320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe49f28e0)
2021-01-27 16:53:53.714 10697-10697/com.example.dashboard D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-01-27 16:53:53.716 10697-10697/com.example.dashboard E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dashboard, PID: 10697
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to parse composition
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$1.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:79)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$1.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:72)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$3.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:96)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$3.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:89)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask.notifyFailureListeners(LottieTask.java:158)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask.access$200(LottieTask.java:27)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieTask$1.run(LottieTask.java:133)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: com.airbnb.lottie.parser.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $
        at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.moshi.JsonUtf8Reader.beginObject(JsonUtf8Reader.java:144)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.parser.LottieCompositionMoshiParser.parse(LottieCompositionMoshiParser.java:57)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonReaderSyncInternal(LottieCompositionFactory.java:389)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonReaderSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:382)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonInputStreamSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:312)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonInputStreamSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:305)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawResSync(LottieCompositionFactory.java:268)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory$3.call(LottieCompositionFactory.java:233)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieCompositionFactory$3.call(LottieCompositionFactory.java:228)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2021-01-27 16:53:53.729 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2021-01-27 16:53:53.729 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe2ea8c50, tid 10724
2021-01-27 16:53:53.733 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2021-01-27 16:53:53.733 10697-10724/com.example.dashboard E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
```

here activity_splash

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Splash">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="900dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/viadeo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=".1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Splash"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo"/>

       <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
           android:id="@+id/lottie"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="200dp"
           app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
           app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/horse1611730774"
           app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appname"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: please post your stack trace

Comment: just added it, might take a look thanks

Comment: Seems like your `lottie` file is corrupt

Comment: I want to see your splash activity XML file

Comment: i just update it on the post

Comment: i think there's something wrong with your lottie file, try another one

Comment: you mean the the lottie i used in raw ?

Comment: yeah, it's saying `Caused by: com.airbnb.lottie.parser.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be that something is wrong with your lottie file, your stacktrace is saying:

`Caused by: com.airbnb.lottie.parser.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $`

So it's possible the Raw resource you're using with lottie just isn't compatible or something went wrong with it, perhaps try a different resource

Comment: thanks. now it work. however can u help me, the animation going good, however the splash screen just going downwards, and not changing screen to main activity.

Comment: no worries, your question was better than the majority of people who post here for the first time, just remember to always post your stack trace if something is crashing, other than that your question was fine, welcome to stack overflow :)